# WebSocket connection failed - ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: elastic-load-balancer

I have a mobile app served with Cloudfront and a backend server on elastic beanstalk and I want to use websockets to allow to two to communicate.

Using just http, the websockets work successfully when using the ws prefix. However, if I need to use wss (websocket secure) if I want my site to use https. So I set up my application load balancer to listen on port 443 and with an SSL certificate that matches the domain I registered on Route 53. I suspect there is something I'm missing involving the SSL certificate.

To recap:

- I have registed a domain with Route 53, www.abc.com
- I created a certificate through Certificate Manager registered to
  www.abc.com
- I associated the certificate to my application load balancer, which
  is routing traffic for my EC2 backend app.
- I have a mobilehub app being served on cloudfront configured to
  websocket connect through the application load balancer.

The full error in my browser console is:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

What am I doing wrong?